# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \\

Tags: python

I am trying to open a CSV file but for some reason python cannot locate it. The csv file is in the same folder with source code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fdrQ.png)

```
path_nag = r'sentiment_dicts/nag.txt'
path_pos = r'sentiment_dicts/pos.txt'
path_not = r'sentiment_dicts/not.txt'

with codecs.open(path_nag, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    nag = f.readlines()
nag_list = [n.replace('\n', '') for n in nag]
with codecs.open(path_pos, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    pos = f.readlines()
pos_list = [n.replace('\n', '') for n in pos]
with codecs.open(path_not, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    not_ = f.readlines()
not_list = [n.replace('\n', '') for n in not_]
```

Comment: Can you paste the code which you used for opening the file here?

Comment: can you show us the directory tree?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the source code is.  What matters is the current directory when you run the program.  You CAN get the path of the source using `os.realpath(os.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: did you try path_nag = r'/sentiment_dicts/nag.txt'? I can't tell if that'll work or not